# Call stored procedure with parameters using Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api2

When I execute this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
use Vcom
go
exec abrir_turno @posto = 'pppe', @turno = '3', @data = '2016-06-13'
```

SQL Server returns a message:

> your SP set pppe to open

I am trying to implement that using Web Api 2 with C#:

```
public IEnumerable<string> spabrirturno(string posto, string turno, string data, string STATUS_TURNO)
{
   STATUS_TURNO = null;

   return obj.abrir_turno(posto, turno, data, STATUS_TURNO).AsEnumerable();
}
```

But I get an error:

> cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable to string

message in photo...

[image]

Comment: I have never programmed a line of C# in my life, but I would bet  good money on that `<string>` says that this function must have a return value of the type `string`, whereas the `AsEnumerable()` method returns a `ienumerable`. Also, these seem two entirely unrelated questions, you should post **one** question per question.

Answer (score 0):

obj.abrir_turno returns a collection of abrir_turno_Result, not string. You will need to select the value you want from the result. Before the AsEnumerable, add

`.Select(m => m.WhateverPropertyName)`